# Spring Customize whitelabel error - redirect

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller, spring-autoconfiguration

I am trying to customize /error by implementing Error controller in a class annonated with RestController.

The Spring Boot app includes autoconfiguration Library and does not explicitly set or use MVC.

```
@RequestMapping("/error")
public String handler(){
return "Error Occurred";
}
```

The above code works fine when the error status is 401 and 404.

```
@RequestMapping("/error")
public void handler(HttpServletResponse response)
{
response.sendRedirect("http://<url>/home");
return;// edit: Even adding this statement is just setting location but not redirecting.
}
```

This is setting location in response with redirect url but not redirecting.

Requirement is to map the /error to external UI page.

Now, when I use, redirectview or responsentity, then, the logic in handler only works when /error is invoked manually and 404 is not invoking /error. It just says This page is not found. Can someone tell me is this because of autoconfiguration Library or am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved. This application has some custom libraries which uses Spring Security. Without access token, this error is occuring. I need to explore more of 401 error but for now, to handle errors am using class with @RestControllerAdvice and set property spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found to true and also, disable whitelabel.

Redirection logic works when the Authorization is successful.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Adding this entry to the application.properties file** : `server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false`.
   This will disable the white label error page entirely.
2. **A Custom Error Controller** :

   ```
    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String handleError(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Object status = request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE);

    if (status != null) {
        Integer statusCode = Integer.valueOf(status.toString());

        if(statusCode == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value()) {
            return "error-404";
        }
        else if(statusCode == HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).value()) {
            return "error-401";
        }
    }
    return "error";
   ```

   }

You can add html pages for the respective errors.

Example : For a 404 error, User will see error-404.html page.

Try below in case you want to redirect to external UI :

```
String redirectUrl = `https://www.yahoo.com";
return "redirect:" + redirectUrl;
```

Comment: The UI of this Service, is external and hence, I am trying to redirect to UI URL but it's not happening

Comment: Well, You should add a `return` statement after redirecting to make it work.

Comment: Updated the answer for more clarification.

Comment: Updated and regarding return statement, it just sets the reponse location to redirected url but doesn't redirect

Comment: return "redirect:" + url; is printing "redirect:<url>" in UI not redirecting

Comment: MVC configurations are autoconfigured using Spring Boot Autoconfiguration library, I want to know if that is causing the issue or is there any thing that needs to be override?